# Customizing CQ / AEM Authentication

Tags: adobe, aem, sling

What exactly do you have to do to authenticate users against an external source while accessing pages on a CQ publish instance?

From what I have read, a custom AuthenticationHandler can be used for this. The AuthenticationHandler can be configured to be called against the paths requiring authentication and inside the extractCredentials() method, the users will be authenticated against the external source and an AuthenticationInfo object will be returned.
If the supplied credentials are invalid, null would be returned from this method to indicate the same. The SlingAuthenticator will then call requestCredentials() where the user can be redirected to the login page.

Is this understanding correct? If so, what does SlingAuthenticator do with the AuthenticationInfo object returned from extractCredentials()?

In some places, having a custom LoginModule (by overriding AbstractLoginModule) is also suggested for the same purpose. Are these 2 different approaches (custom AuthenticationHandler and Loginmodule) for having custom authentication or are they used together somehow? If so, how do they interact?

And also, the concept of CUG (Closed User Group) can be used to redirect users to the login page if they don't have access to a page. Can CUG still be used with a custom auth mechanism or it only works if the users are present in CQ repository?

Any light shed on this would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. The `AuthenticationInfo` object ultimately contains a JCR user id -- but rather than having to use the JCR password for the user, a 3rd party service basically says "this user has authenticated successfully and can access the repository as X".

Example: you're using OpenID or SAML to verify a user is X. user X is then mapped to a user Y in the repository.

I haven't used `LoginModule` but from what I'm reading, that's just extending login processing for the JackRabbit repo. So, rather than using `AuthenticationHandler` to redirect a user to some other place and processing the response, you're plugging further down into the chain where there's already `AuthenticationInfo` (or something like that) being given to JackRabbit to verify and return a session for a user.

So, let's say you did successfully authenticate with OpenID but the user you're mapped to doesn't exist. You could write a login module to create the user in this case (and assign user to a default group). For instance, if user came in with a gmail id, the JCR user could be `gmail_$id`. And the login module, seeing the name starts with `gmail`, will know it's ok to create that user automatically.

As far as CUG, yes, all the above can be used in conjunction with it. Basically, if a request doesn't have access to a resource and the request hasn't been authenticated, the authentication handling system kicks in. If a user has authenticated but still doesn't have access to the resource (e.g. not part of a group that can read it), a 403 will be generated.